# Dell E5450 - mSATA not found by BIOS but is by Linux Live CD

Tags: linux, laptop, bios, dell-latitude, msata

I have a Dell Latitude E5450 with a 128GB mSATA drive, which has been working fine for 3 months.  I have the latest firmware for the BIOS (A10).  I have Fedora 22 installed on this disk and have had no issues until this week.

When booting I get a message "No boot device found".  I had a look in Diagnostics and it tells me it couldn't find any hard disks.  I looked in the BIOS and it also doesn't show any disks.  Hitting F12 for the boot menu shows no internal hard disk.

If I boot a Linux live CD (Fedora, or any other recovery CD), run "fdisk -l" I can see /dev/sda (the drive the BIOS can't find!).  Now if I reboot, the disk is detected and the OS on the disk boots just fine.

If I reboot again, it works fine.  If I power down the laptop, the problem starts again.

I'm not looking for the following answers because the disk boots once detected, these options are not answers to this question:

- suggest changing the boot order
- suggest changing the AHCI/IDE option (it's not an option on this laptop)
- suggest changing the SATA operation option (AHCI or RAID)

Comment: What happens if you just let Linux boot, and then reboot the system? `fdisk -l` doesn't do any magic, it just looks for disk-like device nodes in /dev and reads those that it finds. Disk detection happens during kernel initialization and/or udev's device node population phase (depending on what exactly you are looking for).

Comment: If the goes from a detected to a not detected status that indicates a hardware problem.

Comment: I have a similar issue on my wife's Dell Inspiron, The SSD keeps disappearing. If I turn on/off the laptop, the SSD will reappear and it works fine. Earlier I managed to fix it, i changed some settings in BIOS and uninstalled some Intel drive management stuff (I have no idea how could that be related to such a thing)  but it was long time ago and I forgot what I did. Now I updated the Windows 8 to 10 , and the issue reappeared :) happy days :) The fact that a Windows software might cause such a thing, it might be related to the fact that the laptop has EFI BIOS.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling - you're right, I don't need to fdisk -l to get it to work, only boot the live CD and restart (I'm making a liveUSB that boots and automatically reboots just to make the workaround simpler).

Comment: @Ramhound - the fact that it's only detected after some software detects it would make me hope there was some software based solution - but pre-boot? (Glad it's under warranty!)

Comment: the UEFI partition has a lot software on it, but i'm not sure how can that influence the UEFI BIOS